# No Code coverage in IntelliJ 2017

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I have written some Test methods using Junit and mockito. My tests run fine. However, I am not able to see code coverage.

[image]

No matter which option I click on, nothing is shown in code coverage.
I clicked on `EDIT to fix configuration seetings` displayed in middle of code coverage window on right. This is what I get :

[image]

[image]

What should I do to get code coverage results ?

This is my folder structure :

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To see coverage for production code change the pattern to `com.cdk.dmg.asset`.

You need to **Enable coverage in test folders** if you want see coverage in tests (this option is disabled on your screenshot and the pattern is set to record data for tests only, hence no results).

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you have the `Coverage` plugin enabled!** (yes, it's named literally just "Coverage")
Enabling it did it for me.

You don't need to download it from Marketplace, the plugin comes bundled with IntelliJ Idea.

It's my understanding that it should be enabled by default ..but for some reason that wasn't the case for me, so it might as well not be the case for you either.

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 I had to change Test Runner to Gradle to solve the same problem in my Gradle-based project.

1. File | Settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
2. Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | [Runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/runner.html)
3. Run tests using: Gradle Test Runner

Only then I was able to see the coverage.

Answer (score -1):

This is my first answer
you can follow the below steps to enable

1. Open Visual studio and goto Extensions
2. Select Manage extension
3. Search fine code coverage and select to enable

you will get red and green lines on your actual methods that showing that how much you covere the code in Unit test case.
[Follow steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWDWf.png)